# Win32 EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW vs EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO

Tags: windows, exception, assembly, x86

I have a question about the EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW and EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO exceptions.

Windows will trap the #DE errors generated by the IDIV instruction and will end up generating and SEH exception with one of those 2 codes.

The question I have is how does it differentiate between the two conditions? The information about idiv in the Intel manual indicates that it will generate #DE in both the "divide by zero" and "underflow cases".

I took a quick look at the section on the #DE error in Volume 3 of the intel manual, and the best I could gather is that the OS must be decoding the DIV instruction, loading the divisor argument, and then comparing it to zero.

That seems a little crazy to me though. Why would the chip designers not use a flag of some sort to differentiate between the 2 causes of the error? I feel like I must be missing something.

Does anyone know for sure how the OS differentiates between the 2 different causes of failure?

Comment: Do you have any documentation indicating that `IDIV` even can produce `EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW`?  I understand that `INT_MIN / -1` is problematic, but the description of `EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW` doesn't appear to include this case.

Comment: @Ben  I verified it experimentally. When I do INT_MIN / -1 , the IDIV instruction results in an EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW, and when I do INT_MIN/0 I get EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO. In both case the exception is thrown after attempted exececution of the IDIV instruction.

Comment: @Scott: Hmmm... MSDN documentation fail.  Not that there's anything unusual about that.

Comment: @Ben I think the MSDN documentation does cover it. For example it says "The result of an integer operation caused a carry out of the most significant bit of the result."

Comment: @Scott: What "carry" is taking place?  I've reported the shortcoming to MSDN feedback.

Comment: @Ben If you do ~(INT_MIN) + 1, which is -INT_MIN, which is what INT_MIN/-1 should be equal to, the value of CF is set to 1. It's a bit nit picky though. I agree that it would be better if the docs where more explicit.

Comment: It's actually even easier to get an overflow, since the source register is `EDX:EAX` but the quotient is stored in `EAX`. So any positive number greater than 2^31 (ie. a 64-bit integer) divided by 1 will cause an overflow. (Unless, of course, your compiler handles 64-bit divisions with a library function. Even then, though, it may still occur.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumptions appear to be correct. The only information available on #DE is CS and EIP, which gives the instruction. Since the two status codes are different, the OS must be decoding the instruction to determine which.

I'd also suggest that the chip makers don't really need two separate interrupts for this case, since anything divided by zero is infinity, which is too big to fit into your destination register.

As for "knowing for sure" how it differentiates, all of those who do know are probably not allowed to reveal it, either to prevent people exploiting it (not entirely sure how, but jumping into kernel mode is a good place to start looking to exploit) or making assumptions based on an implementation detail that may change without notice.

---

**Edit:** Having played with kd I can at least say that on the particular version of Windows XP (32-bit) I had access to (and the processor it was running on) the `nt!Ki386CheckDivideByZeroTrap` interrupt handler appears to decode the ModRM value of the instruction to determine whether to return `STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO` or `STATUS_INTEGER_OVERFLOW`.

(Obviously this is original research, is not guaranteed by anyone anywhere, and also happens to match the deductions that can be made based on Intel's manuals.)

Comment: I'm not really looking for anything, other than to understand how it's implemented. I know it can be implemented by manually decoding the instruction and loading the argument but that just seems like a strange way to do it.

Comment: @Scott Since the processor doesn't provide any way to detect it apart from decoding the instructions, there is no alternative. The Intel docs say that no state modification occurs, and EIP isn't even advanced past the instruction. I imagine there's more than once case where this is relevant (illegal opcode is the most likely) and in any case, decoding a ModRM value isn't that hard - there'll be a function in the kernel that does it.

Comment: I know it isn't hard. It just seems an efficient way to do it. Perhaps its not that bad, when compared to doing a stack walk. In any case, I read that page (the one about #DE)in the Intel Manual and thought "they must be decoding the instruction, that's interesting". I wanted to know if that's what it was really doing though.

Comment: @Scott I haven't traced it completely, but it seems that `nt!Ki386CheckDivideByZeroTrap` is the function you're looking for (at least on Windows XP 32-bit). Early on the default return value is set to `STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO`, followed by quite a large switch statement which appears to be decoding the instruction to find the divisor and testing whether or not it is actually zero. (I hope I haven't breached too many licences by doing that...)

Answer (score 2):

Zooba's answer summarizes the Windows parses the instruction to find out what to raise.

But you cannot rely on that the routine correctly chooses the code.

I observed the following on 64 bit Windows 7 with 64 bit DIV instructions:

- If the operand (divisor) is a memory operand it always raises EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO, regardless of the argument value.
- If the operand is a register and the lower dword is zero it raises EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO regardless if the upper half isn't zero.

Took me a day to find this out... Hope this helps.